# Is it possible to extend an attribute?

Tags: c#

In an app, I use different frameworks/technologies to serialize/deserialize objects. To ignore properties in the objects there are attributes like `BsonIgnore`  or `JsonIgnore`.

```
[JsonIgnore]
[BsonIgnore]
public bool MyProperty
{
    get;
    set; 
}
```

How can I create an attribute that extends from `BsonIgnore` and `JsonIgnore` so that I only need to specify one attribute for `MyProperty`?

The following does not work as an attribute has to extend `System.Attribute`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyIgnoreAttribute : BsonIgnore, JsonIgnore
{ ... }

-------------------------

[MyIgnore]
public bool MyProperty
{
    get;
    set; 
}
```

Comment: `JsonIgnore` and `BsonIgnore` are both sealed classes, so you can't extend them. What are you trying to do?

Comment: C# only supports single class inheritance anyway

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, it might be helpful to point out you can declare attributes together, comma separated, ie. `[JsonIgnore, BsonIgnore]`. It's the same as declaring them in their own lines/brackets. Personally, I'd rather see that than seeing `[MyIgnore]` and not knowing what it does at a glance...

Comment: I checked too and saw they were both sealed, I think what you're trying to achieve is not worth the effort. Two attributes in this case is actually better design.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I just wanted my models to be framework/technology agnostic. Whenever I change the serializer I have to update every model and add an import and add the new attribute to the property. That's why I wanted to abstract the framework somehow.

Comment: Maybe you need to ask yourself _why you have so many properties that you want to ignore?_

Comment: It's not that much really. I can live with this effort. It's just the fact that a model shall be independent of any framework. I know that Json.net allows to write custom serializers. This would probably be a solution. Not sure whether all other frameworks support this, though.

Comment: Ah.  Not a problem then

Comment: @Stephan If I had to deal with several frameworks (Json.Net, EntityFramework, ...) I have an application model and a model for each framework and automapper for the mapping between app models and persitance models

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks for the hint about automapper. Just checked it out. I like the idea. Maybe I'm gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# doesn't support multiple-inheritance, and each of those types is `sealed`, so they couldn't be inherited from anyway. But there may be a different approach to do what you're trying to do.

If it is a predictable thing, for example: if something which has one attribute should always have the other attribute; you could use Aspect-Oriented Programming to inject the other attribute at compile time.

Your next question is going to be *"how do I do that?"*, the answer to which will depend on what product you use.

Your question after that will be *"which product should I use to do AOP?"*, which is off-topic, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622024/opensource-alternative-to-postsharp-that-supports-easy-custom-attributes) (hint: take a look at the linked page).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now that it's not possible. AOP just seems to be too much effort, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's useless and impossible.

Look at source code of `JsonIgnoreAttribute`:

```
namespace Newtonsoft.Json
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Instructs the <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer" /> not to serialize the public field or public read/write property value.
  /// </summary>
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
  public sealed class JsonIgnoreAttribute : Attribute
  {
  }
}
```

As you see, it does nothing.

In newtonsoft framework [there is a code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/7217c484e9705b5e76585c8b7fcd489c8e021c23/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L1552), that check that property has `JsonIgnoreAttribute` and do special work for that. It expects JsonIgnoreAttribute only.

Also, `JsonIgnoreAttribute` is sealed, you can't extend it.

Comment: It's not useless. Currently, every model has a dependency on `XxxIgnore`. If I change the framework, I have to go through every model, include a new import and update the attribute. The model shall be framework/technology agnostic. When you add another framework then there is another import and every property in question gets another attribute. I just hoped to leave the properties as is and abstract away this attribute.